# Meaning of the code - visual basic 6 class file

Tags: vb6

What's the meaning of below line of code?

```
Public Sub Update( _
       Optional ByVal astrJDE_SUPPLIER_ID As String = MISSING_STRING, _
)
```

What is the meaning of **'MISSING_STRING'**? **OR** is this **user-defined** variable?

Comment: The default value for an `Optional` parameter must be a literal or constant value. That's obviously not a literal `String` so it must be a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MISSING_STRING is user defined constant

Comment: There's no such thing as a constant variable. They are, by definition, opposites. A constant has a constant value, i.e. a value that doesn't change, while a variable has a value that can vary, i.e. a value that can change.

Comment: To expand on @MSallal's answer: in the VB6/VBA IDE, right-click on it and select 'Definition' from the popup menu. This should take you to the relevant (in this case) constant declaration.